# DIV Overflow Overide

Tags: html, css

Can someone please show me how to make my content within

```
`#content-text`
```

to show a y axis scroll when the content doesn't fit. Currently it follows the hidden tag within the body element. Thanks!

```
body,html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 100%;
}

#content-bg {

    padding: 2em;
    background-color: #362720;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    right: 3.3%;
    bottom: 6.4em;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: 3;
    min-height: 20%;
    overflow:auto !important;
    overflow-style:auto !important;

}

#content-text {

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 4;
    font-weight: lighter;
    overflow:auto !important;
    overflow-style:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: '<div id="content-bg">
     <div id="content-text"><h1>ADVENTURES</h1><p>
  
LOTS OF TEXT IN HERE THAT NEEDS TO SCROL VERTICALLY


  </div>
</div>'

Comment: Post your **HTML** or make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

Set a height or a max-height value to #content-text, then set

```
overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content-bg {
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: #362720;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    right: 3.3%;
    bottom: 6.4em;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: 3;
    min-height: 20%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden
}
```